# Get .NET target platform in visual studio post build event

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I need to run different tasks with .NET 3.5 / .NET 4.0, but the post build event does not have a macro representing the target framework version.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. It might help if you explained what the actual end goal is (i.e. what exactly do you want to do post-build?). Last resort hack: create separate project files for each framework.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019 You should be able to write two post build events, and attach the right conditions to them so that they each work for a certain target framework.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo $(TargetFramework)
echo $(TargetFrameworkVersion)
```

outputs:

```
netcoreapp3.1
v3.1
```

Comment: It seems your solution works only for SDK-style projects